# php how could i kill a process by PID when safe_mode is on

Tags: php, process, kill, pid

i need to kill a process by PID, but safe_mode is on and i can't use posix_kill or exec or shell_exec and something like that! what should i do ?

Comment: Don't run in safe mode? Killing doesn't appear to be safe.

Comment: Nothing...<asdasdhasjaslkdklasdsa>

Comment: i know that but i can't access to php.ini in anonymous server

Comment: you shouldn't have the need to kill a process in a simple shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

If your PHP configuration prevents you calling functions to kill a process (e.g. `posix_kill` and `safe_mode` enabled) then there is not much you can do about.

Probably the PHP version is outdated and it's possible to inject machine code to kill a process into PHP. However that is not trivial nor really a viable solution.